# jQuery Autocomplete showing result label as undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

The list is being filtered properly but the label is showing as undefined. When I select the item, the value is binded.

Below is my code along with the screenshots:

```
    $(document).on('ready',function(){
        $('#search').autocomplete({
            source: function(req,res) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/search",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "GET",
                    data: {
                        term: req.term
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        res($.map(data, function(item) {

                            return {
                                label: item.name,
                                value: item.id
                            };
                        }));
                    },
                    error: function(xhr) {
                        alert(xhr.status + ' : ' + xhr.statusText);
                    }
                });
            },
            select: function(event, ui) {

            }
        });
    });
```

**Before Selection**
 [image]

**After selection**
[image]

I tried debugging the label and value using alert function. The values are perfect. I'm unable to figure out the error.

```
item.name
item.id
```

Here is the callback response:

```
        [
        {
        "id":"1",
        "name":"Android"
        },
        {
        "id":"2",
        "name":"Akira"
        },
        {
        "id":"3",
        "name":"Andy"
        },
        ....


        ]
```

Comment: What response did you get on success callback?

Comment: @PankajMakwana added the callback response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning different property names in ajax success function.

Can you try to use these property names instead.

```
[
   {
      "label":"1",
      "value":"Android"
   },
   ....        
]
```

Comment: Thanks, man. I added quotes around label and value and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "url",
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
    },
    success: function (res) {
        //console.log(res);
        var obj = JSON.parse(res);

        $('#od').html('<option value=""> Select</option>');
        for (var i = 0, len = obj.length; i < len; i++){
            $('#id').append('<option value='+ obj[i].item_id +'> '+ obj[i].item_name +'</option>');  
        }
    }
});
```

here is my code for get all option you can try this